# Using bootstrap sass (npm) with gulp

Tags: npm, gulp, bower

I git cloned this repo https://github.com/HosseinKarami/fastshell and it has everything worked.

I moved away from compass as fastshell is much faster with gulp. But I'm confused and don't know how to extend it, how can I use boostrap sass (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)? do bower install or npm?

Comment: This is **not** an answer to a question that is **not** a question. What is it that is not working? What have you tried? Show the code and you'll get some help. Notice that this is your first comment in 6 hours.

Comment: @WilmerSaint I need a clue how to plug in boostrap sass into fastshell. My problem is I don't have clue

Answer (score 4):

Zak's answer will get you on a right track, here is more detailed one based on Fastshell's gulpfile.

1) Install bootstrap-sass

```
bower install boostrap-sass --save
```

2) Include bootstrap-sass in Fastshell main scss file

File:

```
src/scss/style.scss
```

With

```
@import "./bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss";
```

Use `gulp css`after this, or watch.

3) Override Bootstrap classes further for customization you need in allready included modules/partials .scss files

Comment: One could do even better and inject bootstrap into main.scss dynamically: .pipe(gulp-inject(gulp.src(['./bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss']), injectBootstrapOptions)). For this to work you'll need **[gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject)** plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

1 Install boostrap-sass using the following bower command:

```
bower install boostrap-sass --save
```

2 Then use gulp-sass which is already required in the project to access the *.scss files in bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets.

Cheers!